# Android L Theme.Material not being recognized

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to change my app's status and navigation bar colors and so far nothing I've tried has worked. My project is targeted to L.

Here is my styles.xml in values-v21 folder.

```
<style name="CalcTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">        
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/primary_dark</item>
</style>
```

The problem is none of these changes are working when I run the project on my Nexus 5 (running L)

Comment: Did you apply the theme in application tag at the manifest xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Change to :

```
<style name="CalcTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material">
```

Answer (score 0):

as of oct 2014 i am able to see the changes in the emulator but not inside the layout preview. just for reference i was refering to this tutorial
https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html